# Best practices on saving in a view, based on example code

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and looking for best practices on the code I just wrote (below). The code currently exists in my view.py and simply creates a new event. Being familiar with other languages it just 'smells bad' if you know what I mean. Could someone point out how they would do this simple task.

The only thing looking at my code again (and from reading the docs a little more), would be to move the request.user into the models.py save function.

Anything else which is a big newbie mistake below?

```
@login_required
def event_new(request):
    # If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        # Check we have valid data
        if form.is_valid():
            # If form has passed all validation checks then continue to save it.
            city = City.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data['autocompleteCity'])
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            event = Event(
                name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                details=form.cleaned_data['details'],
                date=form.cleaned_data['date'],
                start=form.cleaned_data['start'],
                end=form.cleaned_data['end'],
                category=category,
                city=city,
                user=request.user,
            )
            event.save()

            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Event has been created.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/events/invite/')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Error')
            context = {'form': form}
            return render_to_response('events/event_edit.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = EventForm

    context = {'form': form}
    return render_to_response('events/event_edit.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You are missing `()` at `form = EventForm()` in the else block.

Comment: @bikeshedder oops, well spotted. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read about [create forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). The `ModelForm` class will save you from copying the fields from the form to the model.

Apart from that this view looks pretty normal to me.

You can even get rid of some of the boilerplate code (`if request.method == "POST"`, `if form.is_valid()`, etc.) with the generic [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) or [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#CreateView). Since you seam to have some special form handling it might not be of any use for you, but it might be worth a look.

This code is not 100% complete (your special logic for cities is missing) but apart from that should be pretty complete and give you an idea how generic views could be used.

### forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class EventForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Event

    def save(self, commit=True):
        event = super(EventForm, self).save(commit=False)
        event.user = self.user
        if commit:
            event.save()
```

### views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class EventCreate(CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    template = "events/event_edit.html"
    success_url = "/events/invite/" # XXX use reverse()

    def get_form(form_class):
        return form_class(self.request.user, **self.get_form_kwargs())

    def form_valid(form):
        form.user = self.request.user

        messages.success(request, 'Event has been created.')
        super(EventCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(form):
        messages.error(request, 'Error')
        super(EventCreate, self).form_invalid(form)
```

### urls.py

```
url(r'event/add/$', EventCreate.as_view(), name='event_create'),
```

Comment: I just updated the description slightly and added an (almost complete) example using the generic CreateView and the ModelForm.

Comment: wow thats really helpful. one last question I promise. Going forward should i be trying to use class based views, is that the new normal?

Comment: I have mixed feelings about class based views. On the one hand they look really cool but on the other hand the control flow is no longer obvious due to the excessive use of Mixins. Since you can mix class based views with normal views I'd say that you should always pick the solution that works best for your current problem. Just don't use class based views because all the other cool kids use them. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this looks great. You have followed the conventions from the docs nicely.

Moving `request.user` to a model would certainly be an anti pattern - a views function is to serve in the request/response loop, so access this property here makes sense. Models know nothing of requests/responses, so it's correct keep these decoupled from any view behavior.

Only thing that I noticed was creating a `category` variable out only to be used in construction of the `Event`, very minor.

Comment: thats interesting to know thanks. so what about adding the request user to a forms.py would that be an anti patten?