# TypeError: render_option() argument after * must be a sequence, not int

Tags: django, django-admin

I am willing to use Django for a school project but I'm encountering several issues.

The one I need help for is described in the title. Basically, I have a *todo* application in which I could add tasks. Now that I added a form in a my view to let the user add a task, I can't access the tasks in the Django admin.

I can still delete them with the admin but each time I try to add or to edit a task through the admin it throws me this error :

```
TypeError at /admin/todo/task/12/`
render_option() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

But, the form I added for the user works well.

My guess is that the `12` we can see the url is making the error but I don't know why. I point out that I'm still kinda new to Django, I didn't find any similar problem (found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/django-non-relational/hewmSRBnONo/ESadsuN59XwJ) but it didn't help me) so I thought it could be a good idea to ask here :). Here are my files :

**todo/models.py**

```
PRIORITY_TYPES = (
    (1, 'Normal'),
    (2, 'High'),
)

class Task(models.Model):
    application = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='esportbets')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)                                                                                                                                                                        
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField(choices=[PRIORITY_TYPES], default=1)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**todo/forms.py**

```
class AddTaskForm(forms.Form):
    application = forms.CharField(max_length=120, initial='esportbets', help_text='the application it is about')
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=120, help_text='the task to do')
    priority = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PRIORITY_TYPES, initial=1)
```

**todo/views.py**

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_task = Task.objects.create(application=form.cleaned_data['application'],
                                           title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
                                           priority=form.cleaned_data['priority'])
            request.POST = None
        redirect('/todo/', RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = AddTaskForm()
    tasks = Task.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    tasks_high = tasks.filter(priority=2)
    tasks_normal = tasks.filter(priority=1)

    template_datas = {'form':form, 'tasks_high':tasks_high, 'tasks_normal':tasks_normal, 'user':request.user}
    return render_to_response('todo/base.html', template_datas, RequestContext(request))
```

**todo/base.html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
<hr /><h3>ADD A TASK</h3><br />
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="add" />
    <input type="reset" value="reset" />
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. todo/models.py: remove the `[]` around `PRIORITY_TYPES`.
2. todo/forms.py: replace the `forms.ChoiceField(...)` by `forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRIORITY_TYPES, initial=1, coerce=int)`

---

Since you are essentially copying data 1:1 from the form to a model, I'd recommend using [`django.forms.ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

If you want to minimize your code further you could use the generic [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#CreateView). I recently wrote an answer to "[Best practices on saving in a view, based on example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657021/best-practices-on-saving-in-a-view-based-on-example-code/14657354#14657354)" which includes some example code.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, that solved my issue. Was Django unable to get the correct value for the priority field because of the _complex_ structure of `PRIORITY_TYPES` ?

Comment: Wrapping your choices in a `[]` was wrong because you already hat a list. It resulted in a list of list of tuples. ChoiceField only knows about strings. It internally just generates a `<select>` field. I just updated my answer and added a link to model forms and generic views which will could make your code a lot shorter and simpler.

Comment: Hi, I already knew about the `django.forms.ModelForm` but I'm not really copying every single field (only 3 of 7 since some of them must be left empty at the creation). About the `[]` around my choices, I guess I forgot to remove them when I moved the double tuple to a variable to pass it to my form :/.

Comment: That is the reason why `ModelForm` gives you the possibility to [control which fields are used with fields and exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#controlling-which-fields-are-used-with-fields-and-exclude). If you need to fill some fields by other means you can do that too: `obj = form.save(commit=False)`, fill the extra fields and then call save yourself. I highly recommend using ModelForm in those cases as it makes the code a lot simpler and less error prone.

Comment: I agree with what you said about making the code simpler, definitely going to use this, thanks. Besides that, the form I added is on the same page than the list of the tasks (the form redirect to the same page) and thus once I add a task through the form, the page reload with the form still filled. Is there any clue you could give me ?

Comment: As you are passing the `redirect` function a `RequestContext` it doesn't look like you are using the correct function. Make sure you use [django.shortcuts.redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). e.g. `from django.shortcuts import redirect` and `redirect('/todo/')`. If your form is still prefilled it is probably the autocompletion of your browser. If you are still having troubles feel free to raise a new question about this.